# Graph QL Apollo Server throwing INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR. Can't find source of error

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, mern

Here is the error being returned from the query playground when I try to run any query.

I really have no idea where this error is originating because from the stack trace it looks like it's deep inside the apollo internals.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Cannot convert undefined or null to object",
        "extensions": {
          "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
              "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object",
              "    at Function.values (<anonymous>)",
              "    at C:\\Users\\ccrow\\Documents\\Repositories\\fullstack-boilerplate\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:343:53",
              "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
              "    at C:\\Users\\ccrow\\Documents\\Repositories\\fullstack-boilerplate\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:8:71",
              "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
              "    at __awaiter (C:\\Users\\ccrow\\Documents\\Repositories\\fullstack-boilerplate\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:4:12)",
              "    at initializeDataSources (C:\\Users\\ccrow\\Documents\\Repositories\\fullstack-boilerplate\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:338:20)",
              "    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\ccrow\\Documents\\Repositories\\fullstack-boilerplate\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:41:15)",
              "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
              "    at C:\\Users\\ccrow\\Documents\\Repositories\\fullstack-boilerplate\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:8:71",
              "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
              "    at __awaiter (C:\\Users\\ccrow\\Documents\\Repositories\\fullstack-boilerplate\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:4:12)",
              "    at Object.processGraphQLRequest (C:\\Users\\ccrow\\Documents\\Repositories\\fullstack-boilerplate\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:34:12)",
              "    at C:\\Users\\ccrow\\Documents\\Repositories\\fullstack-boilerplate\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\runHttpQuery.js:164:62",
              "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
              "    at C:\\Users\\ccrow\\Documents\\Repositories\\fullstack-boilerplate\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\runHttpQuery.js:8:71"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is a link to my project repo: [project repo](https://github.com/ccrowley96/fullstack-boilerplate)

Here is a link to the server index file which starts the apollo-server and the express app: [index.js](https://github.com/ccrowley96/fullstack-boilerplate/blob/main/server/index.js)

Comment: log data in resolvers before return? .... missing async/await in resolvers?

Comment: Fixed the issue.  Was just missing some parens.  Took HOURS to figure out haha.  Thanks for the reply : )

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue.

My server initialization code looked like this:

```js
// Initialize Graph QL Apollo server
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => {
    users: new Users(User)
  ), 
  context
});
```

I needed to put brackets around the dataSources return type to properly return an object.  Arg... Such an annoying syntax error.  Took forever to find, but maybe this will help some other poor soul with the same problem.

#### Fixed

```js
// Initialize Graph QL Apollo server
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => ({
    users: new Users(User)
  )), 
  context
});
```